# How to replace Metamask Pop-Up with my own UI

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, gui

I was wondering if I can replace the Metamask pop-up with my own pop-up/user interface.

**Example:** Currently on my dApp a user clicks "Buy Token" and a Metamask modal pops up and says the usual confirm/reject. Instead of this pop-up with the Metamask UI/logo is it possible when the user clicks "Buy Token" my own company branded personal pop-up happens instead?

Essentially I want to have the pop-up be re-branded to my own logo and add some information explaining what's happening.

Thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are connecting your DApp with the blockchain using the browser web3 instance, which is provided by metamask. The alternative is to use Infure or your own node and change the web3 provider, then metamask will not pop-up and you can implement your own logic when someone click on a button to send a transaction, but then it is more complicated.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Interesting, yea that would be more complex. Thanks though!